The term watched tags changed to "Following" which conflicts with the already used followed posts
I noticed that in last few days, the [watched-tags] that was previously shown at the top-left side of the page has been changed to [Following]. This is confusing because we already have something called "Following" in our profile page's Activity tab which shows us the posts that we are following.
So I think changing [watched-tags] to [Following] as shown in the screenshot below should be corrected.
Here is the screenshot of before this update:


And below is the screenshot of what is currently the case:


Below is the screenshot showing that we already have "Following" in our profile tab:


It's part of Upcoming sign-up experiments related to tags and this was already pointed out to the company there

@VLAZ I see, but still "Following" should not be used in place of "Watched-tags"
